# How to transfer an Excel Ribbon to a different user name

Tags: excel, ribbon

I have an excel ribbon with about 25 macros and sent it to another user with a different user name, so obviously the macros point to a different location. How can I remedy this? Change the user name on one computer to match the other one? I also copied the personal.xls file to the other computer, so could I just create a new user on the second computer with the same name as the first computer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this. I first renamed the custom tab on PC2 from "My Tools" to "My Tools PC1", then created a new tab called "My Tools PC2". Then, I recreated all the groups and added in all the macros as in the first tab. These then pointed to the active Personal.xls file. Finally, I unchecked the My Tools PC1 tab and checked the new tab.

Problem solved. I can now swap the personal.xls and the ribbon files, and all it takes is for me to activate the proper one.